# Best tool to remove dos line ends and join line back up again

Tags: linux, replace, line

I have a csv file into which has crept some ^M dos line ends, and I want to get rid of them, as well as 16 spaces and 3 tabs which follow.  Like, I have to merge that line with the next one down.  Heres an offending record and a good one as a sample of what I mean:

```
"Mary had a ^M
                  little lamb", "Nursery Rhyme", 1878
"Mary, Mary quite contrary", "Nursery Rhyme", 1838
```

I can remove the ^M using sed as you can see, but I cannot work out how to rm the nix line end to join the lines back up.

```
sed -e "s/^M$             //g" rhymes.csv > rhymes.csv
```

UPDATE

Then I read "However, the Microsoft CSV format allows embedded newlines within a double-quoted field. If embedded newlines within fields are a possibility for your data, you should consider using something other than sed to work with the data file." from:
http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq4.html

So editing my question to ask Which tool I should be using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With help from [How can I replace a newline (\n) using sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/sed-how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n/1252191#1252191), I made this one:

```
sed -e ':a;N;$!ba;s/\r\n                \t\t\t/=/' -i rhymes.csv
```

`<CR> <LF> <16 spaces> <3 tabs>`

If you just want to delete the CR, you could use:

```
<yourfile tr -d "\r" | tee yourfile
```

(or if the two input and output file are different: `<yourfile tr -d "\r" > output`)

Comment: I tried that and it does not work for me, the closest I get is with ctrl-v ctrl-m to generate ^M

Comment: tr is neat but it did not join the lines.  The sed solution worked - I can then go on and use tr to rm any consecutive spaces throughout the file, thanks a lot.

Comment: tr translate (or delete) characters.
If you wanted to delete the LF too, you would use `cat yourfile | tr -d "\n\r" | tee yourfile`

Comment: `tr -d "\r" <yourfile |tee yourfile` -- useless use of `cat` :)

Answer (score 2):

```
dos2unix  file_name
```

to convert file, or

```
dos2unix old_file new_file
```

to create new file.

Comment: Thanks. It left me with the problem of re-identifying and removing this line end in the middle of a record though.